# FileMaker: creating a plot from a variable list

Tags: filemaker

I would appreciate help with a Filemaker question about creating an x-y plot.

I have a list of numbers to plot for x and a list of numbers to plot for y. I read the numbers into separate variables and then read the values into separate fields.  I ran the script below to load the variable.  I then tried to plot with X-Axis data = Xaxis and Y-Axis data = Yaxis.  Nothing gets plotted.  Could I please have help how to correctly plot these numbers?  Below is the script and the chart setting.  For example, I would like to plot x=-5,y=-5, x=-4.5,y=-4.5, et. The plot should be linear.  Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you have at-least one record created in the table.
2. Data Source should be "Current Record (delimited data)"

[image]